# Many left join on the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have  a table in 2 different database. Table1 in DataBase1 and Table2 in database2.

Table1 and Table2 have the same columns with different rows content.

each row correspond to a parcel number (TShipping_Tracking or TShipping_Reference or TShipping_OrderRef or TShipping_Barcode) and an ID (TShipping_ID). Remarque: for each parcel (row) only 1 of the 4 column , related to parcel number, listed above is not null

These are the schema of the table in each database:

```
create table Database1..Table1 (TShipping_ID varchar(50),TShipping_Tracking varchar(50),TShipping_Reference varchar(50),TShipping_OrderRef varchar(50),TShipping_Barcode varchar(50))

create table Database2..Table2 (TShipping_ID varchar(50),TShipping_Tracking varchar(50),TShipping_Reference varchar(50),TShipping_OrderRef varchar(50),TShipping_Barcode varchar(50))
```

Moreover, I have the table Database1..Reject having the same columns as Table1 (and Table2) exept TShipping_ID:

```
create table Database1..Table3(TShipping_Tracking varchar(50),TShipping_Reference varchar(50),TShipping_OrderRef varchar(50),TShipping_Barcode varchar(50))
```

I want to retreive TShipping_ID of the parcel that does not exist in Database1

I did the following query but it has a very bad response time:

```
select isnull(isnull(isnull(D2t1 .TShipping_ID,D2t2.TShipping_ID),D2t3.tshipping_id),D2t4.tshipping_id) as TShipping_ID
from Database1..Table3 D1t3
left join Database1..Table1 D1t1 on D1t3.TShipping_tracking=D1t1.TShipping_tracking
left join Database1..Table1 D1t2 on D1t3.TShipping_Reference=D1t2.TShipping_Reference
left join Database1..Table1 D1t3 on D1t3.TShipping_OrderRef=D1t3.TShipping_OrderRef
left join Database1..Table1 D1t4 on D1t3.TShipping_barcode=D1t4.TShipping_barcode
left join Database2..Table2 D2t1 on D1t3.TShipping_tracking=D2t1.TShipping_tracking
left join Database2..Table2 D2t2 on D1t3.TShipping_Reference=D2t2.TShipping_Reference
left join Database2..Table2 D2t3 on D1t3.TShipping_OrderRef=D2t3.TShipping_OrderRef
left join Database2..Table2 D2t4 on D1t3.TShipping_barcode=D2t4.TShipping_barcode
where D1t1.TShipping_Tracking is  null and D1t2.TShipping_Reference is  null and D1t3.TShipping_OrderRef is null and D1t4.TShipping_BarCode is null
```

Does anyone has a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: look up the `coalesce` function rather than use isnulls like that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Table1.TShipping_ID` is a `NOT NULL` field:

```
SELECT t2.TShipping_ID
FROM Table3 t3
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.TShipping_Tracking  = t3.TShipping_Tracking
    OR t2.TShipping_Reference = t3.TShipping_Reference
    OR t2.TShipping_OrderRef  = t3.TShipping_OrderRef
    OR t2.TShipping_Barcode   = t3.TShipping_Barcode
LEFT JOIN Table2 t1
    ON t1.TShipping_Tracking  = t3.TShipping_Tracking
    OR t1.TShipping_Reference = t3.TShipping_Reference
    OR t1.TShipping_OrderRef  = t3.TShipping_OrderRef
    OR t1.TShipping_Barcode   = t3.TShipping_Barcode
WHERE t1.TShipping_ID IS NULL
```

This will still be slow as hell, not the least of which because it's pretty close to a `CROSS JOIN`, but you don't supply enough information about what you're doing or what the key fields of the tables are to make me think you can replace the `OR` with `AND` in the join conditions.  I suspect that may be the case, however.